# Why does the JVM have the iconst_2 - iconst_5 opcodes?

Tags: java, jvm, opcodes

While reading the JVM specification (as one does), I was very surprised when I came across the 7 `iconst_<i>` opcodes. After all, there is only one byte to play with.

I very rarely write the literals for 2, 3, 4 or 5 in my code. I can understand why -1, 0 and 1 might be treated specially, but it seems amazing to me that the designers would want to blow 4 precious opcodes on numbers that just happen to be quite small.

Does anyone know if there's a good reason for this? Am I underestimating the benefit of these?

Comment: There are 255 op codes available. It's quite hard to use anywhere near all of them when designing a VM instruction set. Obviously Jim Gosling thought it was a good dea, and it's cost-free until you run out, like giving away free theatre tickets, so why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, your assumption is correct: just to make the bytecode smaller and Java interpreter a tiny bit faster (there were no JIT compiler those times). Note that these bytecodes may be used much more often than you expect. For example, consider the following code:

```
int[] a = {10, 20, 30, 40};
```

Effectively it's compiled to something like:

```
int[] a = new int[4];
a[0] = 10;
a[1] = 20;
a[2] = 30;
a[3] = 40;
```

So here `iconst_0` to `iconst_4` are used even though you have no such constants in the source code.

Answer (score 5):

Hope this can Clarify your Question Why waste the 4 Opcode ..

See the Byte Code of this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int b = 20;
        int c = 5;
        int d= 6;
    }
```

part of Byte Code

```
0: bipush        20
 2: istore_1
 3: iconst_5
 4: istore_2
 5: bipush        6
 7: istore_3
```

As you can see for number greater 5 it's starts using `bipush`which are typically less efficient than the equivalent `iconst_<n>` and also take up more bytes in the class file.

> bipush    `byte1` expands `byte1` to an int and then pushes it onto the
>   stack, because every slot on the Java stack is 32 bits wide (JVM is Stack Based Virtual Machines)

And to see if **`bipush` takes up more byte** ..

See the class file size of two following code.(This size are on my 64bit machine.. it may differ on your machine but the difference will be same)

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int b = 5;

    }

}
```

> size 406 bytes

now if i replace `b =6` ;
the size of the same class file becomes `407 bytes` which remains constant till even when `b=127` which also uses `bipush`. This difference in Size is due to the fact that bipush has 2 bytes, one byte opcode, second byte immediate constat value

**bipush format:**

```
bipush
byte
```

as you can see from the line `5: bipush        6` in bytecode while `iconst_<n>` uses 1 byte only.

> So such bytecodes are defined for some commonly pushed numbers, to 
>   increase the efficiency of bytecode execution and reduce the size of
>   bytecode streams.

and as Tagir said those numbers would be used more often than you would think